# jQuery code to toggle

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code and would like to my customer to either hover on and off the magemenu or click it to close the megamenu only. How can this be done

```
.bind('mouseleave', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass('hovered');
    $this.children('div').hide();
});
```

Please adivce on how to add toggle. Thanks

Comment: Can you post jsfiddle link?

Comment: Sorry! I cant help you without your actual code